# Android - [Glide] Using Disk Cache

Tags: android, caching, android-glide

I am developing an app which shows Images in `RecyclerView` by the help of the amazing library `Glide`. As the number of image gets higher, so does the memory usage. The thing is.. When I check the cache usage of my app using ES File Explorer, it says 0KB and this is weird.. I used :

```
Glide.with(context)
.load(youtubeShareThumbnailUrl)
.diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
.skipMemoryCache(true)
.centerCrop()
.into(((ObjectViewHolder) holder).userPostShareYoutubeImage);
```

Am I just understanding "cache" wrong? What I think is :

Memory Cache is what shows on the Android Monitor, in the "Memory" tab, and Disk Cache is the app cache shown in the ES File Explorer.

Exceeding Memory Cache for an app will cause OOM error, whereas Disk Cache doesn't really have any limit as it is stored in storage.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry if i don't get your question right, if you are tying to cache the image in disk then I would suggest get rid of the skipMemorycache(true) bit.
And AFAIK glide loads the image once and saves them to disk cache for further use (if enabled) therefore the use of memory (ram) is not noticable when you load the same image or image sets for the second time :)

Comment: Hmm I thought `skipMemoryCache()` is for indication of not using Memory as cache.. What is that for btw? And how to enable disk caching then? Because when I scroll back up, although it is small, but it is still quite noticable..